# php version required for Zend Navigation to work

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-navigation

does anybody know what minimum php version do you need to get Zend Navigation working? If I recall it didn't work with 5.1 though it was long ago, not sure if I am not confusing something

Comment: Do you have problems using the latest PHP version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/requirements.introduction.html

> Zend recommends the most current release of PHP for critical security and performance enhancements, and currently supports PHP 5.2.4 or later.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty cool stuff from this guy

http://wolf-u.li/3128/information-on-the-minimum-required-version-of-php-of-each-component-of-zend-framework/

PHP-Compatibility of each version of Zend Framework

http://zfcompat.wolf-u.li/

For **Zend Framework 1.10.6**

```
| Zend/Navigation/*                                                 | 5.2.0   |
| Zend/Navigation/Page/*                                            | 5.0.0   |
```